# In march 2022 (version 1.66), how to set terminal.findMatch？

Tags: visual-studio-code

```sh
"terminal.findMatch": true,
"terminal.findMatch.borderColor": "red"
```

Not at all

In march 2022 (version 1.66), how to set terminal.findMatch？

Answer (score 2):

Those are not standalone settings, they are `colorCustomizations` and are set in the settings `colorCustomizations` (`settings.json`) like so:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "terminal.findMatchBorder": "#ff0000",

       // you should get intellisense below for more findMatch color properties you can set
    "terminal.findMatch.......
}
```